# Retrieve Specific Element in Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have created an array and as an example, using my sample array, I want to search for the [entity_id] element and retrieve the [value] element associated with it. For my example array if I searched for entity_id 4 it would return a 1. How do I do this with PHP?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 1
        [value] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2
        [value] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 3
        [value] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 4
        [value] => 1
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $array[array_search('4', array_column($array, 'entity_id'))]['value'];
```

get the outer key by extracting the entity_id column and searching that, then use that key to access the inner value